# Convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' to 'System.Data.DataColumn'

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am trying to convert a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn to a DataTable Column, or link them together,

Problem is when i try this i recieve the following error :  `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' to 'System.Data.DataColumn'`

What ways would there be to link, string or convert one to the other ?

I use the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Plan_de_lucru_1._0
{
    public partial class frPlanMain : Form
    {
        private void AddAutoIncrementColumn()
        {
            DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
            column.AutoIncrement = true;
            column.AutoIncrementSeed = 1000;
            column.AutoIncrementStep = 10;

            // Add the column to a new DataTable.
            DataTable table = new DataTable("NrFir");
            table.Columns.Add(NrFir);
        }


        private void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string MySheet = "WI";
            string MyPath = "D:\\" + locTBox.Text + ".xls";
            string constr = "Provider = MicroSoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + MyPath + ";Extended Properties =\"Excel 8.0; HDR=NO;\";";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + MySheet + "$]", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();



        sda.Fill(dt);
        dGVPlan.DataSource = dt;
        new SearchWindow(this).Show();

    }

  }
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**

I have added the code for the Form1 Designer:

```
namespace Plan_de_lucru_1._0
{
    partial class frPlanMain
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        public System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
            this.NrFir = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.DECHzvar = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.DECHLP = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.DECH = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.AddressSystem = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Prierez = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Farba1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Farba2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Dlzka = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Typvodica = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.PoziciaL = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.L = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.ADDL = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.PoziciaR = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.R = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.ADDR = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Mspec = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.TypMspec = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.KontaktL = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.SealL = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.KontaktR = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.SealR = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dGVPlan)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // locTBox
            // 
            this.locTBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 13);
            this.locTBox.Name = "locTBox";
            this.locTBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(175, 20);
            this.locTBox.TabIndex = 0;
            this.locTBox.Text = "374MJFE257 LWB Plan de lucru";
            // 
            // GoButton
            // 
            this.GoButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(193, 13);
            this.GoButton.Name = "GoButton";
            this.GoButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 20);
            this.GoButton.TabIndex = 2;
            this.GoButton.Text = "Incarca";
            this.GoButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.GoButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.GoButton_Click);
            // 
            // dGVPlan
            // 
            this.dGVPlan.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dGVPlan.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.NrFir,
            this.DECHzvar,
            this.DECHLP,
            this.DECH,
            this.AddressSystem,
            this.Prierez,
            this.Farba1,
            this.Farba2,
            this.Dlzka,
            this.Typvodica,
            this.PoziciaL,
            this.L,
            this.ADDL,
            this.PoziciaR,
            this.R,
            this.ADDR,
            this.Mspec,
            this.TypMspec,
            this.KontaktL,
            this.SealL,
            this.KontaktR,
            this.SealR});
            this.dGVPlan.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
            this.dGVPlan.GridColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
            this.dGVPlan.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 54);
            this.dGVPlan.Name = "dGVPlan";
            this.dGVPlan.ReadOnly = true;
            this.dGVPlan.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;
            this.dGVPlan.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1291, 288);
            this.dGVPlan.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(982, 12);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(321, 36);
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 4;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(81, 35);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(41, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 5;
            this.label1.Text = "Masina";
            // 
            // NrFir
            // 
            this.NrFir.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.NrFir.DataPropertyName = "F1";
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.NrFir.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
            this.NrFir.Frozen = true;
            this.NrFir.HeaderText = "NrFir";
            this.NrFir.Name = "NrFir";
            this.NrFir.ReadOnly = true;
            this.NrFir.Resizable = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
            this.NrFir.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
            this.NrFir.Width = 54;
            // 
            // DECHzvar
            // 
            this.DECHzvar.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.DECHzvar.DataPropertyName = "F2";
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.DECHzvar.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle2;
            this.DECHzvar.Frozen = true;
            this.DECHzvar.HeaderText = "Tech. Sudura";
            this.DECHzvar.Name = "DECHzvar";
            this.DECHzvar.ReadOnly = true;
            this.DECHzvar.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
            this.DECHzvar.Width = 97;
            // 
            // DECHLP
            // 
            this.DECHLP.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.DECHLP.DataPropertyName = "F4";
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.DECHLP.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle3;
            this.DECHLP.Frozen = true;
            this.DECHLP.HeaderText = "Tech. LP";
            this.DECHLP.Name = "DECHLP";
            this.DECHLP.ReadOnly = true;
            this.DECHLP.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
            this.DECHLP.Width = 76;
            // 
            // DECH
            // 
            this.DECH.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.DECH.DataPropertyName = "F3";
            dataGridViewCellStyle4.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.DECH.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle4;
            this.DECH.Frozen = true;
            this.DECH.HeaderText = "H-Nr.";
            this.DECH.Name = "DECH";
            this.DECH.ReadOnly = true;
            this.DECH.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
            this.DECH.Width = 57;
            // 
            // AddressSystem
            // 
            this.AddressSystem.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.AddressSystem.DataPropertyName = "F5";
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.AddressSystem.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle5;
            this.AddressSystem.Frozen = true;
            this.AddressSystem.HeaderText = "Address System";
            this.AddressSystem.Name = "AddressSystem";
            this.AddressSystem.ReadOnly = true;
            this.AddressSystem.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
            this.AddressSystem.Visible = false;
            this.AddressSystem.Width = 107;
            // 
            // Prierez
            // 
            this.Prierez.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.Prierez.DataPropertyName = "F6";
            dataGridViewCellStyle6.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.Prierez.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle6;
            this.Prierez.Frozen = true;
            this.Prierez.HeaderText = "Sectiune";
            this.Prierez.Name = "Prierez";
            this.Prierez.ReadOnly = true;
            this.Prierez.Width = 74;
            // 
            // Farba1
            // 
            this.Farba1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.Farba1.DataPropertyName = "F7";
            dataGridViewCellStyle7.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.Farba1.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle7;
            this.Farba1.Frozen = true;
            this.Farba1.HeaderText = "Culoare 1";
            this.Farba1.Name = "Farba1";
            this.Farba1.ReadOnly = true;
            this.Farba1.Width = 77;
            // 
            // Farba2
            // 
            this.Farba2.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.Farba2.DataPropertyName = "F8";
            dataGridViewCellStyle8.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.Farba2.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle8;
            this.Farba2.Frozen = true;
            this.Farba2.HeaderText = "Culoare 2";
            this.Farba2.Name = "Farba2";
            this.Farba2.ReadOnly = true;
            this.Farba2.Width = 77;
            // 
            // Dlzka
            // 
            this.Dlzka.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.Dlzka.DataPropertyName = "F9";
            dataGridViewCellStyle9.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            dataGridViewCellStyle9.NullValue = null;
            this.Dlzka.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle9;
            this.Dlzka.Frozen = true;
            this.Dlzka.HeaderText = "Lungime";
            this.Dlzka.Name = "Dlzka";
            this.Dlzka.ReadOnly = true;
            this.Dlzka.Width = 72;
            // 
            // Typvodica
            // 
            this.Typvodica.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.Typvodica.DataPropertyName = "F10";
            dataGridViewCellStyle10.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.Typvodica.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle10;
            this.Typvodica.Frozen = true;
            this.Typvodica.HeaderText = "Tip Cablu";
            this.Typvodica.Name = "Typvodica";
            this.Typvodica.ReadOnly = true;
            this.Typvodica.Visible = false;
            this.Typvodica.Width = 77;
            // 
            // PoziciaL
            // 
            this.PoziciaL.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.PoziciaL.DataPropertyName = "F11";
            dataGridViewCellStyle11.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.PoziciaL.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle11;
            this.PoziciaL.Frozen = true;
            this.PoziciaL.HeaderText = "Pozitie Stanga";
            this.PoziciaL.Name = "PoziciaL";
            this.PoziciaL.ReadOnly = true;
            // 
            // L
            // 
            this.L.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.L.DataPropertyName = "F12";
            dataGridViewCellStyle12.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.L.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle12;
            this.L.Frozen = true;
            this.L.HeaderText = "Cav. St.";
            this.L.Name = "L";
            this.L.ReadOnly = true;
            this.L.Visible = false;
            this.L.Width = 70;
            // 
            // ADDL
            // 
            this.ADDL.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.ADDL.DataPropertyName = "F13";
            dataGridViewCellStyle13.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.ADDL.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle13;
            this.ADDL.Frozen = true;
            this.ADDL.HeaderText = "Add. St.";
            this.ADDL.Name = "ADDL";
            this.ADDL.ReadOnly = true;
            this.ADDL.Visible = false;
            this.ADDL.Width = 70;
            // 
            // PoziciaR
            // 
            this.PoziciaR.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.PoziciaR.DataPropertyName = "F14";
            dataGridViewCellStyle14.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.PoziciaR.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle14;
            this.PoziciaR.Frozen = true;
            this.PoziciaR.HeaderText = "Pozitie Dreapta";
            this.PoziciaR.Name = "PoziciaR";
            this.PoziciaR.ReadOnly = true;
            this.PoziciaR.Width = 96;
            // 
            // R
            // 
            this.R.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.R.DataPropertyName = "F15";
            dataGridViewCellStyle15.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.R.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle15;
            this.R.Frozen = true;
            this.R.HeaderText = "Cav. Dr.";
            this.R.Name = "R";
            this.R.ReadOnly = true;
            this.R.Visible = false;
            this.R.Width = 66;
            // 
            // ADDR
            // 
            this.ADDR.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.ADDR.DataPropertyName = "F16";
            dataGridViewCellStyle16.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.ADDR.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle16;
            this.ADDR.Frozen = true;
            this.ADDR.HeaderText = "Add. Dr.";
            this.ADDR.Name = "ADDR";
            this.ADDR.ReadOnly = true;
            this.ADDR.Visible = false;
            this.ADDR.Width = 66;
            // 
            // Mspec
            // 
            this.Mspec.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.Mspec.DataPropertyName = "F17";
            dataGridViewCellStyle17.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.Mspec.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle17;
            this.Mspec.Frozen = true;
            this.Mspec.HeaderText = "M spec.";
            this.Mspec.Name = "Mspec";
            this.Mspec.ReadOnly = true;
            this.Mspec.Width = 65;
            // 
            // TypMspec
            // 
            this.TypMspec.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.TypMspec.DataPropertyName = "F18";
            dataGridViewCellStyle18.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.TypMspec.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle18;
            this.TypMspec.Frozen = true;
            this.TypMspec.HeaderText = "Tip M spec.";
            this.TypMspec.Name = "TypMspec";
            this.TypMspec.ReadOnly = true;
            this.TypMspec.Visible = false;
            this.TypMspec.Width = 81;
            // 
            // KontaktL
            // 
            this.KontaktL.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.KontaktL.DataPropertyName = "F19";
            dataGridViewCellStyle19.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.KontaktL.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle19;
            this.KontaktL.Frozen = true;
            this.KontaktL.HeaderText = "Terminal St.";
            this.KontaktL.Name = "KontaktL";
            this.KontaktL.ReadOnly = true;
            this.KontaktL.Width = 81;
            // 
            // SealL
            // 
            this.SealL.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.SealL.DataPropertyName = "F20";
            dataGridViewCellStyle20.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.SealL.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle20;
            this.SealL.Frozen = true;
            this.SealL.HeaderText = "Gumita St.";
            this.SealL.Name = "SealL";
            this.SealL.ReadOnly = true;
            this.SealL.Width = 75;
            // 
            // KontaktR
            // 
            this.KontaktR.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.KontaktR.DataPropertyName = "F21";
            dataGridViewCellStyle21.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.KontaktR.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle21;
            this.KontaktR.Frozen = true;
            this.KontaktR.HeaderText = "Terminal Dr.";
            this.KontaktR.Name = "KontaktR";
            this.KontaktR.ReadOnly = true;
            this.KontaktR.Width = 82;
            // 
            // SealR
            // 
            this.SealR.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            this.SealR.DataPropertyName = "F22";
            dataGridViewCellStyle22.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.SealR.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle22;
            this.SealR.Frozen = true;
            this.SealR.HeaderText = "Gumita Dr.";
            this.SealR.Name = "SealR";
            this.SealR.ReadOnly = true;
            this.SealR.Width = 76;
            // 
            // frPlanMain
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1310, 354);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dGVPlan);
            this.Controls.Add(this.GoButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.locTBox);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "frPlanMain";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Plan de lucru";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.frPlanMain_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dGVPlan)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox locTBox;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Button GoButton;
        public System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dGVPlan;
        public System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn NrFir;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn DECHzvar;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn DECHLP;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn DECH;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn AddressSystem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Prierez;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Farba1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Farba2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Dlzka;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Typvodica;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn PoziciaL;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn L;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ADDL;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn PoziciaR;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn R;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ADDR;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Mspec;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn TypMspec;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn KontaktL;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn SealL;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn KontaktR;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn SealR;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `NrFir` defined?

Comment: It is defined in the DataGridView, i created a column in the DataGridView, it has the TexBoxColumn property. What i am actualy trying is to link a column to any F1 column from the .xls files i load to the DataTable.

Comment: Added Edit 2 with the Form1 designer code.

Comment: this `table.Columns.Add(NrFir);`  should be `table.Columns.Add(column);`. a typo?

Comment: Problem is if i do that the column i add does not retrieve data from column F1 from a .xls

Comment: Would it be possible to referance to        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn NrFir; ?

Comment: It is within the class so it is accessible. `Designer` and `Cs` belongs to same class, just they are partial.

Comment: Could you tell me how to reference to it, in Form1 ? Please